# How do I center an image in HTML sent through javamail?

Tags: java, html, css, spring-boot, jakarta-mail

I have sourced and passed the images to the mail body using

```
            messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            DataSource fds1 = new FileDataSource( "images\\IG.png");
            messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds1));
            messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-ID", "<IG>");
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);


            messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            DataSource fds2 = new FileDataSource( "images\\Twitter.png");
            messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds2));
            messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-ID", "<Twitter>");
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);


            messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            DataSource fds3 = new FileDataSource( "images\\web.png");
            messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds3));
            messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-ID", "<web>");
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
```

and have applied a style to center the image. It works well when viewed with a web browser, but the images are moved to the left when the email is sent. The circle style applied to the images is applied when viewed from a browser and in Gmail.

Another problem is that an image I source from Figma in the HTML template displays as an attachment, how can I make it display as an image instead of an attachment?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, e-mails do not support full CSS and the only way to center things in e-mail clients are with tables. Something like:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
    <td align="center">
        <img ... />
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```